# save form value in post_meta wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
function yummy_sounds_custom(){
    add_menu_page( 
        __( 'Custom Menu Title', 'textdomain' ),
        'Licence',
        'manage_options',
        'licence',
        'licence_fields',
        '',
        6
    ); 
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'yummy_sounds_custom' );



/**

 * Display a custom menu page

 */
function licence_fields() {
    ?>
    <h2>Fill the licence details</h2>

    <form method="post" action="">
    <div>Licence Title :</br> <input type="text" name="title" /></div>
    <div>Licence Tagline :</br> <input type="text" name="tagline" /></div>
    <div>Price :</br> <input type="text" name="price" /></div>
    <div>Currency Symbol :</br> <input type="text" name="symbol" /></div>
    <div>Description :</br> <textarea rows="7" cols="50" name="description"></textarea></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></div>
    </form>
```

I am new for customization of wordpress so i have no idea how to save data in wordpress table .I am creating this form in custom admin menu and want to save data in post_meta how i can do it any help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could involve Wordpress Ajax functionality for this: [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Save data with **update_option** and read it with **get_option** functions. This is scenerio for single license.

If you like to create collection of licenses, just like posts for example, you must create new [custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). Then you will have post id in new post type, and you could use **update_post_meta** and **get_post_meta**.

Answer (score 0):

post_meta's datas are linked to a specific post, if you want to save global data you need to use [update_option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) and [get_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/).

Comment: function dwwp_meta_save(){
 
 if( isset($_POST['title']))
 {
 update_option('title', $_POST['title']);
 $value = $_POST['title'];

}}